# C/C++: Converting hexadecimal value in char to integer

Tags: c++, c, char

I have hexadecimal values stored as characters:

```
char A = '0';
char B = '6';
char C = 'E';
```

... I need them coverted to integers. I know 'atoi', but this only works for decimal coded char values. Any similar function?

Comment: Apart from `atoi` what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `strtol`. But `strtol` needs a 0 terminated `char *`, so:

```
long x = strtol((char[]){A, 0}, NULL, 16);
```

Comment: But please note, `(char[]){}` requires a recent compiler version with support for C++11 initialization syntax.

Comment: @BenVoigt Actually we've had it since C99.

Answer (score 7):

```
int v = (A > '9')? (A &~ 0x20) - 'A' + 10: (A - '0');
```

is correct for ASCII.  For other character sets, a similar approach would work, but you would then want `toupper` instead of `&~ 0x20`.

Comment: I need new value as integer, not char.

Comment: @jurij: `char` is an integral type, plenty big enough to hold 0-15, but I changed it to make you happy.

Comment: @junj, replace `char v` with `int v`. You do know that `char` is just the shortest signed integer type, right?

Comment: Yes, but I need new values as int to do some math with them later.

Comment: This is very encoding dependent.  It supposes, for example, that the codes for 'A'-'F' and 'a'-'f' are larger (numerically) than the codes for '0'-'9'.  Which is true for ASCII, but not necessarily for other encodings.  (It's not true for EBCDIC, for example.)

Comment: @jurij: You can use either `char` or `int`; the choice is yours. `char` will be automatically promoted to `int` if you do arithmetic with it.

Comment: I think it should be `((A &~ 0x20) - 'A' + 10)`.

Answer (score 3):

In C:

```
const char chrs[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

int value = -1; // sentinel
const char *loc = strchr(chrs, ch);
if (loc)
    value = loc - chrs;
```

or, using C++:

```
const std::string chrs("0123456789ABCDEF");
int value = chrs.find(ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can explicity state you want to use base 16 with `strtol`

```
char C = 'E';
int num = strtol (&C ,NULL,16); // 14
```

Beware that `C` is not a **null terminated array**, simply solved if you can change your characters to the following:

```
char C[] = "E";
int num = strtol(C, NULL, 16);
```

Comment: `&C` is not a null-terminated array!

Comment: Should work on little endian systems if `C` is `short`, `int`, `long` or any other integer type with larger size than `char` :) (also the pointer should be casted to `char *` then)

Comment: It's undefined behavior, which is more than just living on the edge.  It may work most of the time, but give a wrong value from time to time.  Or even crash (although I'll admit that I find that highly unlikely).

Comment: Granted, but this illustration was targeted at the use of `strtol` and it's optional base capabilities. I'll make some amendments.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to make a one character string, and use the
standard conversion techniques on it:

```
std::istringstream tmp( std::string( 1, A ) );
tmp >> anInt;
```

It's a bit heavy, however (to put it lightly), and probably not very
efficient in terms of runtime (a litote if I ever heard one).

One simple and robust solution is a table lookup:

```
static char const digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
int value = std::find(digits, digits + 16, A) - digits;
if (value >= 16) {
    //  A wasn't a hex digit...
}
```

Alternatively (and much faster) is to use the character as an index into
a table:

```
static signed char const values[] =
{
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,     //  0x00-0x07
    //  ...
     0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,     //  0x30-0x37
     8,  9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,     //  0x38-0x3F
    -1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, -1,     //  0x40-0x47
    //  ...
    -1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, -1,     //  0x60-0x67
    //  ...
};


int value = values[static_cast<unsigned char>( A )];
```

Note that this is **very** dependent on the encoding;  you might want to
build it up at runtime from a list of digits, to avoid any encoding
issues.  Something like:

```
struct ValueTable
{
    signed char values[256];
    ValueTable()
    {
        std::fill( begin(values), end(values), -1 );
        static char const digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        for ( int i = 0; i < 16; ++ i ) {
            values[ digits[i] = i;
            values[ tolower( digits[i] ) ] = i;
        }
    }
};
static ValueTable const map;

//   ...
int value = map.values[ static_cast<unsigned char>( A ) ];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int xtoi(char c)
{
    int v = -1;
    char w=toupper(c);
    if(w >= 'A' && w <= 'F'){
        v = w - 'A' + 0x0A;
    }else if (w >= '0' && w <= '9'){
        v = w - '0';
    }

    return v;
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    printf("v:%p\n",argc == 2 ? xtoi(argv[1][0]):-1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but mine involved also verifying that it was a valid 
Hexidecimal character. Below is my solution that converts from hex char to a 
binary nibble. (Note: You may want to change uint8_t to int).

The benefit of this approach is that instead of individually checking each
character against a lookup table. There is only up to 6 comparison (aside from
the null pointer guard) before it can output the answer.

```
/**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @brief Converts Hexidecimal Char Value Into Binary Nibble Format
  Converts 0-9 & a-f & A-F Hex notation to binary nibble between 0x00 to 0x0F
  Return: True if valid nibble is avaliable at nibble_out else it returns false
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
bool char_to_nibble(const char ch, uint8_t *nibble_out)
{ /* Assumes char ch is encoded in ascii */
  if (!nibble_out)
  { /* Output Pointer Cannot Be Null */
    return false;
  }
  if ( '0' <= ch && ch <= '9' )
  { /* Integer Character */
    *nibble_out = ch - '0';
    return true;
  }
  if ( 'a' <= ch && ch <= 'f' )
  { /* Lowercase Letter Character */
    *nibble_out = ch - 'a' + 10;
    return true;
  }
  if ( 'A' <= ch && ch <= 'F' )
  { /* Upper Case Character */
    *nibble_out = ch - 'A' + 10;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

The above function is confirmed to be functional. Proof in test program below.

## Test Program

This program demonstrates char_to_nibble() and it's usage.

```
/*******************************************************************************
  Parse Hexidecimal Char to binary Nibble ( In C Language )
  Brian Khuu 2017
*******************************************************************************/
// Tip: tcc -run ${This File}
#include <stdint.h>  // Standard Integer (e.g. uint8_t )
#include <stdbool.h> // Standard Boolean
#include <stdio.h>   // printf()
#include <ctype.h>   // isprint()
#include <stdio.h>   // sscanf()

/**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @brief Converts Hexidecimal Char Value Into Binary Nibble Format
  Converts 0-9 & a-f & A-F Hex notation to binary nibble between 0x00 to 0x0F
  Return: True if valid nibble is avaliable at nibble_out else it returns false
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
bool char_to_nibble(const char ch, uint8_t *nibble_out)
{ /* Assumes char ch is encoded in ascii */
  if (!nibble_out)
  { /* Output Pointer Cannot Be Null */
    return false;
  }
  if ( '0' <= ch && ch <= '9' )
  { /* Integer Character */
    *nibble_out = ch - '0';
    return true;
  }
  if ( 'a' <= ch && ch <= 'f' )
  { /* Lowercase Letter Character */
    *nibble_out = ch - 'a' + 10;
    return true;
  }
  if ( 'A' <= ch && ch <= 'F' )
  { /* Upper Case Character */
    *nibble_out = ch - 'A' + 10;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

/*******************************************************************************
  Demonstration of char_to_nibble()
*******************************************************************************
  - Running this program without an argument will spit out the full table.
  - Running this program with one char per argument will run a partial test.
*/

void test(const char ch)
{ /* Runs a test on this char and display the result */
  uint8_t nibble = 0;
  /* Function Under Test */
  bool result = char_to_nibble(ch, &nibble);
  /* Print Result */
  printf("| 0x%02X, `%c` | %2u     | %s |\r\n", (uint8_t) ch, (isprint(ch)?ch:' '), nibble, (result?"**TRUE**":" FALSE  ") );
}

#define ARGTOINT(arg, var) if((argc-1) >= arg){sscanf(argv[arg], "%d", &var);}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("| Input     | Output | Is Hex?  |\r\n");
  printf("|-----------|--------|----------|\r\n");
  if (argc == 1)
  { /* self test on no param */
    for (uint16_t i = 0 ; i < 256 ; i++) test((char)i);
    return 0;
  }
  for (int i = 1 ; i < argc ; i++)
  { /* Process user input (e.g. "a b c d e ..." )*/
    char ch = *(argv[i]);
    test(ch);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

## Full Table Output

This table was generated by running the above test program (empty arg mode).
This demonstrates that this function is working as expected.

````
| Input     | Output | Is Hex?  |
|-----------|--------|----------|
| 0x00, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x01, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x02, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x03, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x04, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x05, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x06, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x07, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x08, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x09, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x0A, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x0B, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x0C, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x0D, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x0E, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x0F, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x10, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x11, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x12, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x13, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x14, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x15, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x16, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x17, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x18, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x19, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x1A, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x1B, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x1C, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x1D, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x1E, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x1F, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x20, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x21, `!` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x22, `"` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x23, `#` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x24, `$` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x25, `%` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x26, `&` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x27, `'` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x28, `(` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x29, `)` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x2A, `*` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x2B, `+` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x2C, `,` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x2D, `-` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x2E, `.` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x2F, `/` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x30, `0` |  0     | **TRUE** |
| 0x31, `1` |  1     | **TRUE** |
| 0x32, `2` |  2     | **TRUE** |
| 0x33, `3` |  3     | **TRUE** |
| 0x34, `4` |  4     | **TRUE** |
| 0x35, `5` |  5     | **TRUE** |
| 0x36, `6` |  6     | **TRUE** |
| 0x37, `7` |  7     | **TRUE** |
| 0x38, `8` |  8     | **TRUE** |
| 0x39, `9` |  9     | **TRUE** |
| 0x3A, `:` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x3B, `;` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x3C, `<` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x3D, `=` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x3E, `>` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x3F, `?` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x40, `@` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x41, `A` | 10     | **TRUE** |
| 0x42, `B` | 11     | **TRUE** |
| 0x43, `C` | 12     | **TRUE** |
| 0x44, `D` | 13     | **TRUE** |
| 0x45, `E` | 14     | **TRUE** |
| 0x46, `F` | 15     | **TRUE** |
| 0x47, `G` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x48, `H` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x49, `I` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x4A, `J` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x4B, `K` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x4C, `L` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x4D, `M` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x4E, `N` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x4F, `O` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x50, `P` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x51, `Q` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x52, `R` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x53, `S` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x54, `T` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x55, `U` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x56, `V` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x57, `W` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x58, `X` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x59, `Y` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x5A, `Z` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x5B, `[` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x5C, `\` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x5D, `]` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x5E, `^` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x5F, `_` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x60, ``` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x61, `a` | 10     | **TRUE** |
| 0x62, `b` | 11     | **TRUE** |
| 0x63, `c` | 12     | **TRUE** |
| 0x64, `d` | 13     | **TRUE** |
| 0x65, `e` | 14     | **TRUE** |
| 0x66, `f` | 15     | **TRUE** |
| 0x67, `g` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x68, `h` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x69, `i` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x6A, `j` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x6B, `k` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x6C, `l` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x6D, `m` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x6E, `n` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x6F, `o` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x70, `p` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x71, `q` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x72, `r` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x73, `s` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x74, `t` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x75, `u` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x76, `v` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x77, `w` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x78, `x` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x79, `y` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x7A, `z` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x7B, `{` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x7C, `|` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x7D, `}` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x7E, `~` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x7F, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x80, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x81, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x82, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x83, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x84, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x85, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x86, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x87, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x88, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x89, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x8A, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x8B, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x8C, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x8D, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x8E, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x8F, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x90, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x91, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x92, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x93, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x94, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x95, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x96, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x97, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x98, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x99, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x9A, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x9B, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x9C, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x9D, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x9E, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0x9F, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xA0, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xA1, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xA2, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xA3, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xA4, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xA5, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xA6, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xA7, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xA8, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xA9, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xAA, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xAB, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xAC, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xAD, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xAE, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xAF, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xB0, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xB1, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xB2, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xB3, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xB4, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xB5, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xB6, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xB7, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xB8, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xB9, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xBA, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xBB, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xBC, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xBD, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xBE, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xBF, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xC0, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xC1, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xC2, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xC3, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xC4, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xC5, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xC6, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xC7, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xC8, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xC9, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xCA, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xCB, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xCC, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xCD, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xCE, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xCF, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xD0, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xD1, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xD2, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xD3, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xD4, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xD5, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xD6, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xD7, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xD8, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xD9, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xDA, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xDB, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xDC, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xDD, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xDE, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xDF, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xE0, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xE1, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xE2, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xE3, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xE4, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xE5, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xE6, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xE7, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xE8, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xE9, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xEA, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xEB, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xEC, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xED, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xEE, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xEF, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xF0, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xF1, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xF2, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xF3, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xF4, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xF5, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xF6, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xF7, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xF8, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xF9, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xFA, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xFB, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xFC, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xFD, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xFE, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
| 0xFF, ` ` |  0     |  FALSE   |
````